# PreClusterCreationValidationFailure when trying to create a cluster through the Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight, azure-powershell

I'm currently working on with `Windows Azure` in order to set up a cluster up and running, following the steps from [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-administer-use-powershell/#provision-an-hdinsight-cluster). But when i tried to execute the `command` i got this error:

`New-AzureHDInsightCluster : Unable to complete the cluster create operation
left behind state: 'Error'. Message: 'PreClusterCreationValidationFailure'.`

I had a look into the [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-debug-jobs/#PreClusterCreationValidationFailure), but i was kinda confused with it. What does the input values mean in it? Is it the `ClusterSizeInNodes`? and also could this error occur due to the same cluster name being already exist?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you will see a PreClusterCreationValidationFailure message if you are supplying arguments that are not compatible with eachother, such as requesting a cluster in one datacenter region and pointing to a default storage container in another region.

If that doesn't happen to be the case, then please include more details about the specific arguments you are providing.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. It was due to the `container name`, where i have given it as "mycontainer". Then i changed it to some other it worked.

Comment: I provided right values but still I get Unable to complete the cluster create operation. Operation failed with code '400'. Cluster left behind state: 'Error'. Message:'PreClusterCreationValidationFailure'.
At line:1 char:1 + New-AzureHDInsightCluster -Config $conf -Credential $creds -Name $clusterName -L
+ CategoryInfo   : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureHDInsightCluster], HDInsightClusterCreateException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.HDInsightClusterCreateException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Cmdlet.PSCmdlets.NewAzureHDInsightClusterCmdlet

Comment: @Vinu, your issue is likely different from the original.  Can you post as a new question, and include the details of any parameters you are passing to New-AzureHDInsightCluster?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your user credentials (`-Credential <PSCredential>`) follow the "requirements"? Unfortunately, they are not documented very well...

- Username: `admin`
- Password: `[min. 10 characters]` (at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit and 1 special character)